# How to deploy sandbox edited code to production in zoho crm

Tags: zoho

**Hi,
I have createdfunction in zoho sandbox and deployed to production. And after some day I get new requirements and edit my that function but I does not found the way to deploy edited function into production site in Zoho CRM.
When I check in the production function hasn't update.
Please let me know if any solution on that.
**

Answer (score 0):

Case:

1. Might be that function deleted from Production. if deleted then created new in Sandbox and deploy.
2. if production Env is working fine then need to refresh your Sandbox Env